# General pipeline for model comparisons

Tags: mixed-model, model

Suppose I run a study where people respond to words, and I want to predict their response times to those words. I have several lexical predictors (e.g., length, frequency) and several semantic predictors (e.g., concreteness, imageability).

I want to know if these semantic predictors predict response times over and above the lexical variables and will test this using linear mixed effects modeling.

I start with the lexical effects and compare a model including length to one only including the intercept. Q1: Is this a good way of evaluating length as a predictor? Q2: How do I decide which lexical variable to test first? Q3: How can I test the inclusion of length as a predictor while also allowing for random slopes, if I have to compare it to a null model only including the intercept which thus cannot include random slopes?

I then test the efficacy of another lexical variable, frequency, as a predictor. Q4: Would I include length (assuming it was found to be a significant predictor) in both models? Or would I test length and frequency separately against models only including the intercept? Q5: Should I include random slopes for all predictors?

Q5: Similarly, when I then go to test various semantic variables by comparing models including a particular semantic variable and whatever lexical variables were found to be significant, against one only including the lexical variables, how do I know what order to do it in? Q6: Should I include whatever semantic variables were found to be significant when I then go to test the next semantic variable?

Thanks so much. If you have a reference for a resource that answers these general questions, and has a general step by step plan for model comparisons of this kind, I would love to hear about it!

Edit: It seems like the specifics I mentioned in my question have obscured my real questions. I'm going to rephrase it in a simpler way.

I have three potential predictors of a dependent variable that I'm interested in evaluating. I want to use model comparisons to evaluate them.

1) How do I know which one to begin with, and test against a model only including an intercept?

2) In testing that model, how do I account for random slopes, if the model I will have to compare to (one only including an intercept) cannot have random slopes?

3) Related to number one, how do I know which order to go about testing the next effects?

4) If Factor1 was found to be a significant predictor, when I go to test Factor2, should I test a model only including Factor2 against one only including the intercept? Or test a model including Factors 1 & 2 against one only including Factor 1?

Comment: Borrowing a page from computational linguistics, why wouldn't you also be interested in how the sound "shapes" of the words matter? E.g., the differences in pronunciation of the phonemes comprising the words, varying them in timber, frequency, etc...like distinguishing between *sa" and *sha* in forming the word "shape"

Comment: We are, my question is more about the approach to analysis than the particular predictors.

Comment: Good. I think there's a danger in the expression of your questions insofar as they seem to presume and/or seek a cut-and-dried, cookbook approach to resolution of the issues. It's neither that simple nor that easy. In other words, if someone comes forth with the "answers," I would be 1) amazed and, 2) skeptical. There is no shortage of research in the areas of interest to you...beginning with computational linguistics. One option is an excellent LinkedIn group moderated by Marina Santini, Webgenre R&D Group. She frequently posts references to research on topics that should be of interest

Comment: Poke around in the activity stream of that group and see if she doesn't cite  a paper or book that addresses your concerns.... https://www.linkedin.com/groups/4301498

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question in a simpler way. I will edit it.

Comment: Simpler? That misses the point since you're still treating your concerns as having unambiguous, straight-forward, risk-free, cookbook answers and solutions. Text analysis is an analytic wild, wild west where there is no consensus, conventions or "best" practices. From one paper to the next the methods change, usages evolve and terminology proliferates. You're going to have to create your own answers and advance the support to defend them.

Comment: It took me a while to dig out this reference but it may help. The title is *Mathematical Methods in Linguistics* available from Amazon here...     http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Linguistics-Studies-Philosophy/dp/9027722455?ie=UTF8&colid=3E9G0WFO52DJG&coliid=I2WW3G7A4KDZ22&ref_=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl